# Можно ли экспортировать проект figma в psd?

Tags: photoshop, figma

Имею проект в figma и хочу его перевести в psd. Это возможно?
adobe Photoshop 2020

Comment: В данный момент, это невозможно. Расскажите какую задачу вам нужно решить? Возможно, это можно сделать другим способом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент такой возможности нет.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью онлайн фотошопа photopea.com. Скачиваешь свою работу из Figma в формате .fig, переходишь на онлайн фотошоп, перетаскиваешь в него свой .fig файл и затем нажимаешь "Файл" - "Сохранить как PSD". Ну в принципе и всё.